# Как получить остаток от деления двоичных чисел в VBA?

Tags: алгоритм, vba

Нужно получить остаток от деления двоичных чисел. Сам только начинаю познавать программирование, поэтому не могу придумать как это воплотить.

Comment: Перевести двоичные в десятичные, получить остаток при делении и преобразовать его в двоичный. Ну как вариант.

Comment: Что такое "двоичные числа" в вашем случае? Как заданы ваши числа? Остаток от деления бывает у *чисел*. У просто *чисел*. "Двоичность" не имеет к этому никакого отношения. Числа двоичными не бывают в принципе. Двоичным может быть только один из вариантов *записи* числа.

Comment: @AnT, позвольте не соласиться. Нет, понятно, речь о системе счисления. Но что такое число? Почему о десятичной записи мы говорим "число", 520/25 - это нормально, а о двоичной так сказать не можем? Давайте уберем понятие систем счисления. Что останется для выражения a/b? 16-ричное число - число, записанное в 16-ричной системе, 10-ричное - в 10-ричной... Какие еще могут быть заложены понятия в выражении "двоичное число"?